# Trying to install Moose-2.000 via PPM/Activestate 5.12 on Win32 - 404 not found

Tags: perl, makefile, module, moose

This is a peculiar error that hasn't come up before.  I'm using PPM in Windows to install modules for Perl. Works fine with tons of modules.  But it seems like something is screwy with the Moose-2.000 package and I have no idea how to fix this.

To duplicate the error:

Install newest version of Activestate on windows machine
PPM into the cmd
search "moose"
mark Moose for install and install it

it says:

```
Moose marked for install
Installing package ... 
  Downloading Moose-2.0000 ... not found
Installing package failed

ERROR: 404 Not Found
```

I added virtually all the repos i could find but this seems to be coming from activestate's.

Forgive me, but I actually have no idea how to install a module manually (without the very simple GUI).  I've downloaded the tar file, unzipped it and ran 'makefile.pl'.  I copied the lib files to the /perl/site/lib folder.

Unfortunately, PPM expects a PPD wrapper (or something) so I can't do a command line install like "ppm install URL-of-package".

Can anyone attempt this and let me know if you have any luck?  If not, please give a step by step on how to install this particular package.  I'd be grateful since a bunch of other stuff (like a Twitter package) depends on it!

Thanks

UDPATE:

ok it looks like v2.000 simply doesn't exist yet for Win32. so i was able to install v1.25 in the following workaround, explained in the activestate bugtracker (see comments)

Workaround:

1) Find the latest available version for your platform here:

http://ppm4.activestate.com/idx/MOO...MY.html

Mouse over the icons in the PPMX column to see the target platform and Perl
version.

2) Copy the URL of the .ppmx file

3) Use the URL as an argument to 'ppm install'. For example, for 5.12 Win x86:

```
ppm install
```

http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x86/5.12/1200/D/DR/DROLSKY/Moose-1.25.ppmx

Answer (score 1):

I can see same problem - it looks like quirk on ActiveState side. On [their package index](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Moose/) there is still only 1.25 available. Maybe just the changes are yet to be propaged to mirrors.

**Edit**: I recently upgraded to Moose 2.0001, which seems to be fixed. However I got conflict with `Class-MOP` that comes with ActivePerl 5.12. It turned out that Class::MOP and Moose has been merged together. Solution was to remove both `Class-MOP` and `Moose` prior installation:

```
ppm rem Class::MOP --force
ppm rem Class::MOP --area perl --force
ppm rem Moose --area perl --force
ppm inst Moose
```

Comment: thanks.  ah, i see. it was released only a week ago.  but is there a way through PPM to install a previous version?  i would install 1.25 if i could.

Comment: Jeff: 'ppm install Moose' should give you the most recent available version.

Comment: have you tried doing that?  it fails with the same error as above. 'install failed: 404 error".  how do i do something like "ppm install moose-1.25"? (that doesnt work either)

Comment: A quirk indeed. It looks like Moose 2.0 built successfully, but did not get properly published to the repository. We're investigating.

Comment: That command worked for me with ActivePerl 5.12.2 x64, but I got a "not found" error when trying a 'ppm upgrade Moose' with 5.8.9. Here's the bug tracking this: http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=89810

Comment: i was on 5.12.1 build 1201.  just updated to 5.12.3 build 1204.  got the same error via ppm.